# Android last checkbox is connected with every other checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I've created a list of checkboxes dynamically, the problem is this,

example: I have the following checkboxes

check1[ ] check2[ ] check3[ ] check4[ ] check5[ ]

now if I click check1 then check5 is now checked

same with check2,3,4.
if I click check5 then only check 5 is clicked
but when I check the IsChecked() status of the checkboxes only the clicked on checkboxes are true (not check5 even if the checkbox shows the graphic unless I've actually clicked it)

the opposite is also true, if I uncheck check1 then check5 unchecks

```
    LinearLayout linearChildren = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linEvents);        
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable checkbox = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_checkbox_design);
    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfEvents; count++) {
        CheckBox event = new CheckBox(ActivityAttend.this);
        event.setText(todaysEvents.get(count).getEventName());            
        event.setButtonDrawable(checkbox);
        linearChildren.addView(event);
    }
```

is this something to do me using the setButtonDrawable? or am I completely missing something obvious?

Comment: Try to move yoru third line into your for loop.

Comment: i'll post it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for iteration you are using the same checkbox drawable all the time. To fix it move your Drawable into your for loop.

```
    LinearLayout linearChildren = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linEvents);        
    Resources res = getResources();
    for (int count = 0; count < numberOfEvents; count++) {
        Drawable checkbox = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_checkbox_design);
        CheckBox event = new CheckBox(ActivityAttend.this);
        event.setText(todaysEvents.get(count).getEventName());            
        event.setButtonDrawable(checkbox);
        linearChildren.addView(event);
    }
```